# Should main always point to a common js file when using conditional exports (require and import) in your package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

In this snippet example from [node docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/packages.html#main-entry-point-export) why is the main field pointing to a common js file and not a `./main-module.js`? I thought because `"type": "module"`you are signifying that the source code is ES modules
so should main point to `./main-require.cjs`?

```json
// package.json
{
  "main": "./main-require.cjs",
  "exports": {
    "import": "./main-module.js",
    "require": "./main-require.cjs"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```